# Qt for Android sends MouseReleaseEvent after 1 second without releasing the screen after screen orientation changed

Tags: android, qt, events, widget

If I implement in a simple Qt Widget application for Android `MousePressEvent()` and `MouseReleaseEvent()` everything seems to work properly first. 
If I change the orientation of the screen (e.g. from Portrait to Landscape) the `MousePressEvent` is still triggered as expected, but the `MouseReleaseEvent()` is triggered automatically after about 1 second, even if it is not released. 
This can be prevented if I move on the touchscreen with less than the second. 
With this behavior, even the guesture events won't work anymore after I changed the screen orientation at least one time.
I also receive the following warning in debugger:

> W libtest5.so: QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method Widget::inputMethodQuery(Qt::InputMethodQuery,QVariant)

I didn't find any help on stackoverflow so far. I tested on different Qt versions up to 5.12 and different Android devices

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMouseEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "press" << event->buttons();
}

void MainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "release" << event->buttons();
}

void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "move"<< event->buttons();
}
```

I expect, that the `mouseReleaseEvent` is only triggered if I lift my fingers from the screen. Again, this happens only if I changed the orientation of the screen at least once.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same behaviour. In my case, the error occured when I switched from Qt 5.6.3 to Qt 5.12 (which also entailed switching from ndk15c to ndk17c and gcc to clang).

Using [QTouchEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html) instead of [QMouseEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html) did the fix for me:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTouchEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents,true);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::TouchBegin)
    {
        qDebug() << "press" << event->buttons();
        return true;
    }
    else if (event->type() == QEvent::TouchEnd)
    {
        qDebug() << "release" << event->buttons();
        return true;
    }
    else if (event->type() == QEvent::TouchUpdate)
    {
        qDebug() << "move"<< event->buttons();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Make sure to call `setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents, true);` in your constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this!